# Magic items that grant initiative bonuses?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, initiative

What are the magic items in D&D 4th edition that grant an item bonus on initiative?

Comment: Could you add more detail to what you want to use the item for? As it is, this is a list question and we don't handle those so well - unless you can add criteria that mean that there can be a single, correct answer that *isn't* just a list of item names, this question might be put on hold.

Comment: A search of 'initiative bonus' on the [online compendium's](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) item list yields 66 items. There's a lot. This does need to be narrowed down, or you should do the same search on the online compendium yourself.

Comment: I´m sorry for asking a bad question. I just need some items for my char and I didn´t know how to search for them. The online compendium is a good tip. I didn´t know about that.

Again, I´m sorry, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Stuff that will improve your question: are you using item rarity, what level are you, and what proportion of your resources are you willing to spend on this?